# Python: What's the right way to make modules visible to a TestRunner?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing, django-testing

after watching a couple of presentations about django testing, I want to code my own TestRunner in order to skip django tests, and create better packages structures for my tests.

The problem is that we've changed the project structure and the test runner can't find the right path to do the tests discovery. This is how my project looks like:

```
project/
  -src/
    - project_name/
      - apps/
      - test/ # Not a good name, i know, will change it
         - some_app/

           - test_models.py
    - manage.py
    - development.db
```

Now, in order to test `test_models.py` I want to do this:

```
$ cd project/src/
$ python manage.py test some_app.test_models
```

The problem is that the test runner can't find that package (`some_app`) and module (`test_models.py`). It changes if I hardcode the name in the test runner, but i don't like to do it. Here's what I do to make it work.

```
test_labels = ["%s.%s" % ("project_name.test", l)
                           for l in test_labels
                           if not l.startswith("project_name.test")]
```

So, if you do

```
$ python manage.py test some_app.test_models
```

It will be rewritten to:

```
$ python manage.py test project_name.test.some_app.test_models
```

And that works fine.

I tried doing `sys.path.append("(...)/project_name/test)` but doesn't work neither.

This is the code of my TestRunner:

```
class DiscoveryDjangoTestSuiteRunner(DjangoTestSuiteRunner):
    """A test suite runner that uses unittest2 test discovery.
    It's better than the default django test runner, becouse it
    doesn't run Django tests and let you put your tests in different
    packages, modules and classes.

    To test everything in there:
        $ ./manage.py test

    To test a single package/module:

        $ ./manage.py test package
        $ ./manage.py test package.module

    To test a single class:

        $ ./manage.py test package.module.ClassName
    """
    def build_suite(self, test_labels, extra_tests=None, **kwargs):
        suite = None
        discovery_root = settings.TEST_DISCOVERY_ROOT
        if test_labels:
            # This is where I append the path
            suite = defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromNames(test_labels)
            # if single named module has no tests, do discovery within it
            if not suite.countTestCases() and len(test_labels) == 1:
                suite = None
                discovery_root = import_module(test_labels[0]).__path__[0]

        if suite is None:
            suite = defaultTestLoader.discover(
                discovery_root,
                top_level_dir=settings.BASE_PATH,
                )

        if extra_tests:
            for test in extra_tests:
                suite.addTest(test)

        return reorder_suite(suite, (TestCase,))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Python import hierarchy is rooted at `project/src`. Thus, the correct Python import path for your `test_models` module is `project_name.test.some_app.test_models`, so that's what I would expect to pass in as a test label.

But you don't like typing the `project_name.test` prefix every time you want to run a specific test module, since all your tests will be located there. That's fine: you're choosing to introduce some implicit non-obvious behavior in exchange for some convenience. You definitely should not add anything to `sys.path` in order to achieve this: the key to Python import sanity is having your import hierarchy for a given codebase rooted in one and exactly one place; overlapping sys.path entries will cause problems like doubled imports of the same module under different names.

Really all you want is a UI convenience, and it looks to me like the test-label-munging code you show is the obvious way to implement that convenience. You don't like having the `project_name.test` prefix hardcoded, but it's going to have to be hardcoded somewhere: there's no way the test runner is going to magically figure out that you want to prepend test labels with `project_name.test`. If you want your `TestRunner` to be more generic, you can pull it out into a setting like `BASE_TEST_MODULE` or some such and prepend the value of that setting to each test label.

Answer (score 2):

Before you continue investing more time into your custom `TestRunner`, I would definitely recommend that you take a look at [`django-nose`](https://github.com/jbalogh/django-nose).

The custom test runner provided by `django-nose` implements [`nose`](http://readthedocs.org/docs/nose/en/latest/)'s test runner which is extremely flexible and provides a lot of options for running your tests. It seamlessly overrides the default `test` management command and allows you to configure default test options in your project's `settings` module.

I'm really recommending it for several reasons:

- The options for the `test` command are fully documented ([take look at the output](https://gist.github.com/2597247))
- nose provides *a lot* of approaches for [test discovery](http://readthedocs.org/docs/nose/en/latest/finding_tests.html)
- Chances are your colleagues are already seasoned nose users
- You didn't have to write the `TestRunner` class yourself

Comment: Nice, thanks. I've been taking a look at nose. I need my PM to approve it though.